# CloudFront: The service name identified from the payload does not agree with the service name specified in the transport header

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to create an automatic CloudFront invalidation like so:

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id=$DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths="/*"
```

But I keep getting this error

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateInvalidation operation: The service name : [ServiceName] identified from the payload does not agree with the service name: "UnknownService" specified in the transport header
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be correct, please check the permission first and then try to invalidation a single file.

For automation, you can reference to the following to create a lambda function which is triggered to invalidate files when ever your origin S3 has PUT events
https://dev.to/vumdao/create-aws-lambda-function-triggered-by-s3-notification-event-9p0